# Unclear what to make of test results

Tags: classification, svm

I'm attempting to classify e-mails using Mallet and an SVM. Below are some test-results, but I'm not sure what to make of them.

The test-set is the most recent e-mails found per project.
The training-set is the most recent e-mails that come after that

So a value of 10/100 on the axis means:

- 10 most recent e-mails as test
- 100 most recent e-mails as training, skipping the first 10

In the end a trained classifier will need to make predictions on a new incoming e-mail about which project it most likely belongs to.

The reason I sort the data by time is that I'd like to use only the most relevant data for training. This is because the topics in mails change over time and a very old e-mail might not add any useful information.

Data I'm using as tokens (they're stored as a graph database):

- e-mail addresses found in header (to, from, cc, bcc)
- words and e-mail addresses found in subject and message body

F2-scores per project as a function of test-size / train-size
[image: F2-scores per Project]
Fraction of instances that have the correct label as their best predicted label:
[image: Accuracy]

Some questions I have:

- Does a horizontal line in the graph mean that adding new information does not matter?
- Is it true that I should use as large a training set as possible?
- Not every project has the same amount of e-mails, so after a while one project will have a larger training set than another. Does this matter?
- Any other insights I might be oblivious to?